# Animated flatlist interpolate issue when app moves into the background

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

When using react-native animated flatlist to create a carousel, all works fine with the interpolate as follows:

`const translateY = this.state.scrollX.interpolate({ inputRange, outputRange: [0, -60, 0] });`

But, when we call out to a separate intent for permissions or going off to a settings page, the X position of my animated flatlist appears to reset to 0 and the object I'm animating (in a carousel) drops to the bottom of the view.

Has anyone got any idea on how to handle that?  I don't know if it's because the scrollX state setting is lost or what...

Thanks

Simon

Comment: It definitely seems to be when the AppState becomes "background" - how can I stop my app redrawing the items?

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone else is using the Animated.FlatList in a similar way to us, the issue related to the useNativeDriver setting.  When set to true and the app was put into the background with an React Native Intent, the FlatList flatlined and lost it's interpolated Y coordinate.  When setting to false, things worked as expected.

Thanks
Simon